# User submit form, but don't save until he register or login

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-security, symfony-routing

I have many forms that user fill on single page, but after user make post, controller will check if form is valid and if user is already logged in then save info.

**Need help with**

If user is not logged in, then redirect him to registration page where he sign up and after sign up he will be auto login, then it should come back to same controller with posted values so it can be saved.

- `$form->isValid && !$this->getUser()` then redirect user to sign up page with this form values saved in session?
- after user sign up or login, then come back to previous controller (without any further action) it should auto saved the previously submitted form. since it was `$form->isValid()`

I'm confused, should I save form values in session and redirect? would it save model values properly?

Also how should I redirect user to registration page, while telling Symfony to come back to same page with post method after login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to follow this structure :

**Case :** After submit form page redirect to register/login page.

1.) Fill the form and after submit form convert post data into serialize array. [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

2.) paste that serialize array in hidden fields or session (Register/Login page).

3.) fill the register form, after registration, send back to previous form page and send hidden data to that page and unserialize them. [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

**Suggestion :** IF you want your post data not show in page then you can use urlencode and urldecode function or any other encoding method you can use.

**Note :** To use session or cookie to send post data from one page to anther page is bad practise. It will be on all pages until you unset/delete it.

**redirect to login page from controller manually**, use following:

```
    $session->set('_security.user_firewall.target_path', $request->getUri());

    throw new AuthenticationException(); // use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
```

**redirect from registration page**, use following:

```
         $key = '_security.user_firewall.target_path'; #where "user_firewall" is your firewall name

        //check if the referrer session key has been set
        if ($this->container->get('session')->has($key))
        {
            //set the url based on the link they were trying to access before being authenticated
            $url = $this->container->get('session')->get($key);

            //remove the session key
            $this->container->get('session')->remove($key);
        }
        // if the referrer key was never set, redirect to a default route
        else{
            $url = $this->generateUrl($routeName);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
```

Comment: you have to check by email id of user, either it is registered user or not. if not redirect them to register page if yes redirect to login page. and serialze post data and send that data to that page and then again redirect to form page if required or just save that post data in db and show success message

Comment: when it redirect to login page. On the browser you will see login page OK ? If yes then on the same page you have to take prev. form data in serialized form in the hidden fields. ? If you are taking if then after login you have to redirect it again in prev form and also send hidden (serialized) data to that page and unserilazed that data. i think its clear. if its not then i have to work on your machine. ;)

Comment: I have manage to figure it out, Thank you for help. I have edited answer with examples

Answer (score 1):

To me the easiest solution is put both pages as div's on the same page and use javascript to hide the unsubmitted form so you don't need to store and repopulate the values.